# Two Python dictionaries with same keys: how to detect the keys whom values don't match?

Tags: python, dictionary

### Use case

I have some (big) files that I want to upload on a given site only when they have changed. For this, I plan to use the following scenario with `Python(3)` as programming language:

1. **Initialization**

   - thanks to `hashlib` module, I create a dictionary with:

     - as keys: the file names,
     - as values: the hashes of the corresponding files,
   - I write this dictionary in a dedicated file (say `hash_file.txt`).
2. **Next steps** (when the files may have changed)

   - thanks to `hashlib`, I create a (new) dictionary with:

     - as keys: the same as in the (old) dictionary, i.e. the file names,
     - as values: the (possibly new) hashes of the corresponding files,
   - I compare this new dictionary with the old one in `hash_file.txt` and the files whom hashes don't match (corresponding to the keys whom values don't match) are uploaded.
   - I replace the old dictionary in `hash_file.txt` by the new one.

### Example

With the following old and new dictionaries:

- `{"file_1":"foo1","file_2":"foo2","file_3":"foo3","file_4":"foo4"}`,
- `{"file_1":"foo1","file_2":"bar2","file_3":"foo3","file_4":"bar4"}`,

the keys to be detected would be `"file_2"` and `"file_4"`.

### Questions

- Is there a better way to do than this scenario?
- If not, what is the best way detect the keys of these two dictionaries whom values don't match?

Comment: I would just compare file modification time (system features)

Comment: Indeed but I should have mentioned that these files are subject to regeneration (recompilation) hence may have different modification time but be the sames (have identical hashes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about keys that are present in one dictionary but not the other, you could do something like the following:

```
d1 = {"file_1":"foo1","file_2":"foo2","file_3":"foo3","file_4":"foo4"}
d2 = {"file_1":"foo1","file_2":"bar2","file_3":"foo3","file_4":"bar4"}

non_matching = []

for k, v1 in d1.items():
  v2 = d2.get(k, v1)
  if v1 != v2:
    non_matching.append(k)
```

`non_matching` then ends up being `['file_2', 'file_4']` as required.

---

If you *do* care about keys that might be in one but not the other, we need to consider the union of keys from the two dictionaries. This could be done as follows:

```
d1 = {"file_1":"foo1","file_2":"foo2","file_4":"foo4"}
d2 = {"file_1":"foo1","file_2":"bar2","file_3":"foo3"}

non_matching = []

shared_keys = set(d1.keys()).union(d2.keys())

for k in shared_keys:
  if d1.get(k, []) != d2.get(k, ()):
    non_matching.append(k)
```

This would then get you `['file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4']`